# asp.net autocomplete Combobox display position

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, combobox, autocomplete

I'm using auto complete jquery combobox as suggested in the following page(http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox) but the problem is whenever we click on the dropdown which is positioned in the bottom of the screen the dropdown is not populted above the combobox instesd displaying below the combobox and hiding below the webpage, so we need to click and drag the entire screen to view the dropdown, How can we make the dropdown to display above(Upwards) when dropdown is present in bottom of the page

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Combobox</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  .custom-combobox {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .custom-combobox-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -1px;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .custom-combobox-input {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
  }
  </style>
  <script>
  (function( $ ) {
    $.widget( "custom.combobox", {
      _create: function() {
        this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
          .insertAfter( this.element );

        this.element.hide();
        this._createAutocomplete();
        this._createShowAllButton();
      },

      _createAutocomplete: function() {
        var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
          value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

        this.input = $( "<input>" )
          .appendTo( this.wrapper )
          .val( value )
          .attr( "title", "" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
          .autocomplete({
            delay: 0,
            minLength: 0,
            source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
          })
          .tooltip({
            tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
          });

        this._on( this.input, {
          autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
            ui.item.option.selected = true;
            this._trigger( "select", event, {
              item: ui.item.option
            });
          },

          autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
        });
      },

      _createShowAllButton: function() {
        var input = this.input,
          wasOpen = false;

        $( "<a>" )
          .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
          .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
          .tooltip()
          .appendTo( this.wrapper )
          .button({
            icons: {
              primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
            },
            text: false
          })
          .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
          .mousedown(function() {
            wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
          })
          .click(function() {
            input.focus();

            // Close if already visible
            if ( wasOpen ) {
              return;
            }

            // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
            input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
          });
      },

      _source: function( request, response ) {
        var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
        response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
          var text = $( this ).text();
          if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
            return {
              label: text,
              value: text,
              option: this
            };
        }) );
      },

      _removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {

        // Selected an item, nothing to do
        if ( ui.item ) {
          return;
        }

        // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
        var value = this.input.val(),
          valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
          valid = false;
        this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
          if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
            this.selected = valid = true;
            return false;
          }
        });

        // Found a match, nothing to do
        if ( valid ) {
          return;
        }

        // Remove invalid value
        this.input
          .val( "" )
          .attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
          .tooltip( "open" );
        this.element.val( "" );
        this._delay(function() {
          this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
        }, 2500 );
        this.input.autocomplete( "instance" ).term = "";
      },

      _destroy: function() {
        this.wrapper.remove();
        this.element.show();
      }
    });
  })( jQuery );

  $(function() {
    $( "#combobox" ).combobox();
    $( "#toggle" ).click(function() {
      $( "#combobox" ).toggle();
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label>Your preferred programming language: </label>
  <select id="combobox">
    <option value="">Select one...</option>
    <option value="ActionScript">ActionScript</option>
    <option value="AppleScript">AppleScript</option>
    <option value="Asp">Asp</option>
    <option value="BASIC">BASIC</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="C++">C++</option>
    <option value="Clojure">Clojure</option>
    <option value="COBOL">COBOL</option>
    <option value="ColdFusion">ColdFusion</option>
    <option value="Erlang">Erlang</option>
    <option value="Fortran">Fortran</option>
    <option value="Groovy">Groovy</option>
    <option value="Haskell">Haskell</option>
    <option value="Java">Java</option>
    <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
    <option value="Lisp">Lisp</option>
    <option value="Perl">Perl</option>
    <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
    <option value="Python">Python</option>
    <option value="Ruby">Ruby</option>
    <option value="Scala">Scala</option>
    <option value="Scheme">Scheme</option>
  </select>
</div>
<button id="toggle">Show underlying select</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please add code and css to your question so we can check what is the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the option `position` of Autocomplete. I used your example and manipulated it a little bit. You can find it here: http://jsfiddle.net/vbox1gm2/

I just set the position option where the Autocomplete initialized to `{ collision: "flip" }`. This makes it possible that the position of the list is defined dynamically.

```
    this.input = $( "<input>" )
      .appendTo( this.wrapper )
      .val( value )
      .attr( "title", "" )
      .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
      .autocomplete({
        delay: 0,
        minLength: 0,
        source: $.proxy( this, "_source" ),
        position: {  collision: "flip"  }
      })
      .tooltip({
        tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
      });
```